# Visual Studio 2019 - run a script on a remote machine before debugging

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging, build-automation

I am debugging a service running on a remote machine, written in C++ and built in Visual Studio 2019. By configuring the Remote Debugger in *Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging*, I am able to deploy the build output to the remote machine and start the application with the debugger attached.

Sometimes, I need to attach to the service when it is already running, or perform some additional setup before it is started - and while in VS Code it would be a matter of adding a *preLaunchTask* in *launch.json*, I cannot find a way to automate that in Visual Studio 2019.

I tried preparing a batch script that would perform these tasks and start the service afterwards, and adding it to the *Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Remote Command* field, but that causes the debugger to attach to *cmd.exe* instead of my program. In *Configuration Properties -> Custom Build Step -> Execute After*, I did not find any step related to debugging or deploying the project other than `Run`, which does not seem to get executed when launching the debugging session.

As a workaround, I can add a post-build event to locally run a script which will copy the generated files to the remote machine and prepare the service, and build the project every time, but this is not ideal - for one, I would have to hard-code the credentials for the remote machine within the script.

**Is it possible to automatically execute a custom command** - preferably on a remote machine - **either after deploy, or before debugging, in a Visual Studio 2019 C++ project?** Alternatively, is it possible to configure the Remote Debugger to run a script whenever a session is launched?